# Calculation of coefficient of a monomial in a polynomials

Tags: binomial-theorem

Consider the polynomial:

$$\Bigg(\frac{1-t^{q+1}}{1-t}\Bigg)^{2q-1}$$

for some positive integer $q$. I wish to compute the coefficients of $t^{q^2+q+1}$ in the above polynomial. One can use the binomial theorem for a negative index maybe, but that would make the calculation very cumbersome. Is there an easier method? (If that makes it easier, we can assume that $q$ is a prime power and we are working in $\mathbb{F}_q[t]$.)

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but $$\frac{1-t^{q+1}}{1-t}=t^0+t^1+t^2+\dots t^q$$

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments the identity
$$\frac{1-t^{q+1}}{1-t}=\sum_{i=0}^qt^i=1+t+t^2+\ldots+t^q,$$
helps a lot. This shows that the coefficient of $t^{q^2+q+1}$ in the $2q-1$-th power of this expression is precisely the number of ways in which $q^2+q+1$ can be partitioned into at most $2q-1$ pieces of size at most $q$. Much has been written about these numbers, for more information see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partitions_in_a_rectangle_and_Gaussian_binomial_coefficients).

Alternatively, the multinomial theorem gives us another expression for your polynomial:
$$\left(\sum_{i=0}^qt^i\right)^{2q-1}=\sum_{k_0+\ldots+k_q=2q-1}\binom{2q-1}{k_0,\ldots,k_q}t^{\sum_{i=0}^qik_i}.$$
It follows that the coefficient of $t^{q^2+q+1}$ is given by
$$\sum\binom{2q-1}{k_0,\ldots,k_q},$$
where the sum ranges over all $q+1$-tuples $(k_0,\ldots,k_q)$ of nonnegative integers satisfying
$$\sum k_i=2q-1\qquad\text{ and }\qquad\sum ik_i=q^2+q+1.$$

Comment: That seems fine, but I am looking for a more explicit answer.